# wordpress calendar with pages for each month

Tags: wordpress

I'm making a wordpress site. It will include an event calendar. This is the first time I’m using wordpress, so i have no idea how to do this. This is the design that it needs to follow. 
[image: calendar design]

As you can see it requires a page for each month. The user has the ability to change between the months. I tried this with the [events manager plugin](http://wp-events-plugin.com), but without any success. Do i need to make it possible to add data through the permalink system? Or is there a plugin that has this feature built in?

Answer (score 0):

If your base theme is twenty ten or twenty eleven it has a default Widget for this 'Post Archives'

It lists the Month / Year, shows total post count for the month (enabled by default),

otherwise you can use this plugin

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-archives/

or you can custom create it

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives

if you use this plugin to add Events it has an option to archive events

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-events/

Comment: But the events needed to display are not sorted on the date added, but have a custom field for when the event will take place.

Comment: how do you created the event ? is it any other plugin like wp events ?

Comment: I have been trying different options, one is a with a category "events" and a custom date field attached to that category. An other option i'm looking into is using a plugin called event manager: http://wp-events-plugin.com/ . But in both cases I can't find a solution for my problem. I will look into the plugin you provided thx

Comment: This archive function is also only for events that are already over. Another problem is that it will be multi language site, I'm using WPML. So i think it would be best to use no event plugins. Create a category with a custom date field. It’s not a problem to only fetch the results that take place within a specific month, the big problem is can i provide additional data in the url so i can divide the events per month? for example www.example.com/category/events/jan or any other month at the end of the url, so that i can fetch this in the loop and only show the appropriate events?